# Cloning and modifiying CZML Packets

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs, czml

I wish to spawn a certain number of copies of `shape1` and `shape2` in different positions that shall only be known at runtime, and be able to programmatically alter their other properties as well.

What is the preferred methodology for referring to, cloning, and modifying CZML Packets?

```
var czml = [{
"id" : "document",
    "name" : "CZML Geometries: Cones and Cylinders",
    "version" : "1.0"
}, {
    "id" : "shape1",
    "name" : "Green cylinder with black outline",
    "position" : {
        "cartographicDegrees" : [-100.0, 40.0, 200000.0]
    },
    "cylinder" : {
        "length" : 400000.0,
        "topRadius" : 200000.0,
        "bottomRadius" : 200000.0,
        "material" : {
            "solidColor" : {
                "color" : {
                    "rgba" : [0, 255, 0, 128]
                }
            }
        },
        "outline" : true,
        "outlineColor" : {
            "rgba" : [0, 0, 0, 255]
        }
    }
}, {
    "id" : "shape2",
    "name" : "Red cone",
    "position" : {
        "cartographicDegrees" : [-105.0, 40.0, 200000.0]
    },
    "cylinder" : {
        "length" : 400000.0,
        "topRadius" : 0.0,
        "bottomRadius" : 200000.0,
        "material" : {
            "solidColor" : {
                "color" : {
                    "rgba" : [255, 0, 0, 255]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}];

var dataSource = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cesium turns CZML into an [EntityCollection](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/EntityCollection.html) full of [Entities](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html) when the CzmlDataSource is loaded.

But before I explain further, some clarification on that dataSource.  If you scroll to the bottom of the example you posted, you see these two lines.  They come from official sample code, but unfortunately they've misled a few folks:

```
var dataSource = Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml);
viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
```

The variable name is a misnomer.  `load` is asynchronous and returns a `Promise` to a dataSource, not an actual dataSource.  To get a reference to the actual dataSource, you have to get a callback when the promise resolves:

```
Cesium.CzmlDataSource.load(czml).then(function(dataSource) {
    viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
    // do more things with dataSource...
});
```

Now that you have a real `dataSource` (inside the async callback), you can find properties like `dataSource.entities` which is your `EntityCollection`.

You can't directly clone an Entity, but you can add `new Entity({ options... })` to an EntityCollection from a generic options object that can be saved and re-used multiple times.  You can also live-edit most of the properties on an Entity to reflect changes at runtime.  Editing entity properties is of course much more performant than destroying and recreating an Entity.

CZML packets are discarded after the EntityCollection is built, but the Entity ID values remain.  You can use [dataSource.entities.getById('...')](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/EntityCollection.html#getById) to find the Entity that was built from a particular CZML packet.

Comment: Thanks; clarifies a lot.
"You can't directly clone an `Entity`, but you can add `new Entity({ options... })` to an `EntityCollection` from a generic options object that can be saved and re-used multiple times."
How do you extract the properties from an `Entity` object created from a CZML Packet (to be saved to a generic options object for re-use)?
Please bear with my dullness; I come from the land of C and C++ and am not well-versed with JS idioms.

Comment: @Slaiyer that's not a typical code path, and Cesium doesn't directly support it.  One option may be to skip CZML entirely, and have the server supply entity creation template objects instead.  Another option could be to use [CzmlDataSource.process](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/CzmlDataSource.html#process) to re-ingest a czml packet with the ID changed, in a loop.